# Safari not retrieving mp4 video from cache, and sometimes timeout when downloading the same resource

Tags: vue.js, caching, video, safari, mp4

I'm running a VueJS application that displays a full screen story of videos. I don't create as many  tag as number of media in my story : I'm just changing component video sources each time I play a new video.

But it looks like Safari (Desktop & mobile) still does not cache HTML video once loaded : when I'm playing again a previous media, Safari is downloading again the asset. Instead of getting from cache like Chrome does.
The same issue has already been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742906/safari-reloading-in-memory-video/52829741#52829741) but sill no correct answer.

Safari even stops downloading the final bytes video (producing a sort of timeout) when we go back and forth quicky in the story, so the story looks stuck. 
Here's an example [link](http://bucket-vue-rocket-staging.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?api_key=892imlqcjcazudiulipbqo50zq3mh3).

Does anyone know a good alternative that avoids re-downloading video data at each play on Safari ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Partial solution**

Found myself a workaround that works pretty well if video is small size - all video are less than 3Mb in my case.

**The trick is to use js fetch API to download full video**, then stream it into video tag.

```
const videoRequest = fetch("/path/to/video.mp4")
    .then(response => response.blob());

videoRequest.then(blob => {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

Contrary to video src attribute, fetch API will get video data from cache if the same video was already fetched before.

Here a [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/needfortri/pen/MdgzPV) that can be tested in Safari desktop/mobile (when NOT in private mode).

**Pro** : Video are now pulled from cache in Safari !

**Con** : You can't start the video until full data has been downloaded. That's why this solution can be used only for small video (like < 5Mb), else your users may wait a while before being able to play the video.